# Out of memory is killing me

Tags: android

I am developing a travel app which use a lot of small images(ex: 120 x 80). 
Sometimes I get that error when I try to load an image (264 x 432 pixels).

```
E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 1824784-byte allocation.
```

This app is not big (30MB) and I don't think that image is too big.
I wonder how other apps using big images work well.
I've searched internet about this issue and many people say bitmap images cause this error. My jpg images stored in the project. Not from the web.
What should I do to solve this? Any advice will be so appreciated. Thanks.

BTW, I am new to Android and using Android Studio and testing on Galaxy note 2.

Comment: You need a full [mcve]

Comment: You need to include the average filesize of the images and how you are loading and displaying them.

Comment: I've found that PNG or GIF format is easier on memory than JPG. But other apps are probably using an Image loader and not loading the entire image

Comment: where do you have these images in drawable or assets as you have mentioned they are in your local device

Comment: use image library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) It's the best image loader ever, aspecially in memory management without any additional settings, has it's own caching method, single line of code, etc. And the best is, it can load gif image with animation too. Even google itself is recommend this library.

Comment: All images are about 4MB. 2.5MB images will be loaded at the beginning of some activities at the same time. Displaying time depends. Can be long or short. They are in drawable files.  But the app doesn't crash in those activities. It happens on another activity which does not load many small images.  Anyway thanks guys for quick replies^^

Comment: I will try it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: regardless whatever the source of the image, loading image in android require caching method to avoid Out Of Memory. The easiest way is using third party ImageLoader.

Comment: hi, I changed most image loading process to Glide's, but I still have out of memory error often. Do you think I missed something or did it wrong way?

Comment: Now I'm using Glide for image loading. I still have the out of memory error. It happens everywhere. Maybe there is some hidden tips for how to use Glide? Most my images are in drawable and some flickr images from web.